# How to get the number of revisions of a Wikipedia article?

Tags: wikipedia

I am interested to know how many revisions a Wikipedia article has. I can look up its history and count the revisions, but I would like a more direct solution than cumbersome manual counting. Ideas?

How to get the number of revisions of a Wikipedia article?

Comment: What do you mean by "review"? Do you mean revisions? Page views? Or something else?

Comment: @AlE. This is a good comment and I think I would mostly mean the number of edits of an article. I would like to have that as a proxy for reliability and good state of an article (being aware of the limitations of this anyway)

Comment: I have edited your question to make this clear. ("Review" on Wikipedia has a specific meaning. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:RVW .) However, I think number of revisions is a poor proxy for reliability and "good state". A high number of revisions only indicates an article is popular, on a controversial subject, and/or old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way is to just add `?action=info` to your URL. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange?action=info quickly tells you it has been edited 366 times.

Comment: This is also available as a link entitled "Page information" in the "Tools" menu (usually found in the left navigation menu).

Answer (score 2):

In combination with what @Ainali suggested, you could use a Google Spreadsheet to further specify your result like so.

### Formula

```
A1 = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange?action=info

=INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 3), 5)
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The `IMPORTHTML` function 'imports' the URL, shown in `A1`, and looks for table number 3. If you're interested in the number of edits only, then use the `INDEX` formula to show only row 5 of that table.